How can I filter my items by references in Sanity
//schemaTypes/component.ts

import { defineField, defineType } from "sanity";

export default defineType({
  name: "component",
  title: "Component",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: "name",
      title: "Name",
      type: "string",
    }),
    defineField({
      name: "slug",
      title: "Slug",
      type: "slug",
      options: {
        source: "name",
        maxLength: 96,
      },
    }),
    ...
    defineField({
      name: "categories",
      title: "Categories",
      type: "reference",
      to: { type: "category" },
    }),
    defineField({
      name: "tags",
      title: "Tags",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: "reference", to: { type: "tag" } }],
    }),
    defineField({
      name: "publishedAt",
      title: "Published at",
      type: "datetime",
      options: {
        dateFormat: "MMM Do YYYY",
        timeFormat: "HH:mm",
      },
    }),
  ],
});

//types/page.ts

interface Query {
  category?: string;
  tag?: string;
}

export const getComponents = async (query: Query): Promise<Component[]> => {
  const url = qs.stringify({
    query: {
      category: query.category,
      tag: query.tag,
    },
  });
  const getComponentQuery = groq`*[_type =="component"] | order(name asc) {
   name,
   author,
   "slug": slug.current,
    link,
   "imageUrl": mainImage.asset->url,
    desc,
    "category": categories[]->slug.current,
    "tag": tags[]->slug.current,
    publishedAt
 }
  `;
  return await client.fetch(getComponentQuery, {
    revalidate: new Date().getSeconds(),
  });
};

I am trying to build a filtering system for my app using Nextjs and Sanity as my backend, and I am having a little bit of a problem figuring out a way to do it. I may be wrong, but it looks like I have to add the filter references dynamically (not hard-coded) on my Groq(adding the tag and category), but I don't know how to go about it. The goal is to filter the components by category and tag slugs, in a way that when I click on a specific category in my app, it renders the components that share that same category, etc. I have spent a long time looking for help on the Sanity Slack channel, but nothing. The GitHub repo is available for anybody wanting to take a closer look. Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
